# Из-за чего возникает Runtime error?

Tags: java, олимпиада

```
Scanner in = null;
PrintWriter out = null;

try {
    in = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    out = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
} catch (Exception e ) {}

byte a = 0, b = 0;
short c = 0;

try {
    a = in.nextByte();
    b = in.nextByte();
    c = in.nextShort();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {}

if (a * b == c) {
    out.print("YES");
    out.close();
} else {
    out.print("NO");
    out.close();
}
```

Не могу понять из-за чего возникает Runtime error. У себя все нормально, а при отправке на проверку на сайт асмп точка ру возникает runtime error, как исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы используете конструкцию `try-catch`, то используйте ее правильно (*а не только для того, чтобы код скомпилировался*).

**Нельзя** оставлять блоки `catch` пустыми. В них нужно обрабатывать возникшую исключительную ситуацию.

С вероятностью, близкой к единице, на сервере отсутствуют файлы `input.txt` и `output.txt`.

В этом предположении, в строке:

```
in = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
```

генерируется исключение `FileNotFoundException`, которые Вы игнорируете (и инструкции, расположенные в этом блоке кода после этой строки не выполняются).

Далее выполнение программы переходит к строкам:

```
byte a = 0, b = 0;
short c = 0;
```

Здесь все нормально. Далее, при выполнении:

```
a = in.nextByte();
```

генерируется исключение `NullPointerException`, так как в этот момент `a == null`, и это исключение Вы тоже не обрабатываете.

И наконец, в строке:

```
out.print("YES");
```

Вы опять получаете `NullPointerException`, так как в этот момент `out == null` И Ваша программа аварийно завершается.